# Create exception in case user input isn't a fraction

Tags: python

```
globals()['fator_pena%s' % x] = Fraction(input("Insert fraction (ex: 2/5): "))
```

I have this code. I wanted to call an exception in case user input isn't a fraction (ex. 2/5).

I have no idea how to start. Could someone help?

Comment: Start with `if` statement. Google `python raise exception` to see how to raise an exception.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to programing. I'll do that.

Comment: Instead of creating new global variable names like this, just use a `dict`. That's what they're for: `fator_pena[x] = ...`.

Comment: I didn't know that, Karl. Looks like I have an entire code to fix (hehe). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple regex and raise the exception if th `fullmatch` fails

```
fraction = input("Insert fraction (ex: 2/5): ")
if not re.fullmatch("\d+/\d+", fraction):
    raise ValueError()
globals()['fator_pena%s' % x] = fraction
```

Comment: @ankh You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I had to wait for the time. However, I had to make a change on the code. Input can't be str. So I had to import Fraction from fractions and update the fraction variable to `Fraction(input("Insert fraction (ex: 2/5): "))` Could you help me out raising an exception for this? Your code requires string.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple validation. You need to check that there is only one '/' character, and both the numerator and denominator are digits.

```
def check_fraction(s):
  values = s.split('/')
  if len(values) == 2 and all(i.isdigit() for i in values) :
    print('True')
  else:
    raise ValueError('Not a fraction')
```

example:

```
>>> check_fraction('79/1')
True
>>> check_fraction('39')
# get a exception with message
```

Comment: Interesting, but doesn't work with Fraction. I had to make a change on the code. Input can't be str. So I had to import Fraction from fractions and update the fraction variable to Fraction(input("Insert fraction (ex: 2/5): ")).

Comment: @ankh - check your input string it just takes values as input like '2/3' or '44'. See the example. BTW its running like charm for me